# Modal que aparece uma vez

Tags: javascript, html, html5, session

Tenho uma modal que quando o cursor do mouse sai da pagina ele aparece uma modal, porém toda vez que sai da pagina ele fica aparecendo, gostaria de saber se há como verificar que a partir do momento que apareceu uma vez ele nao aparece mais ate que  de um refresh na pagina? Somente utilizando o HTML e JS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" onmouseleave="abreModal()">
   <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

   <title>Document</title>
   <script type="text/javascript">


      function abreModal() {
          opsc = document.getElementById("openModal").style.opacity = "1";
          disp = document.getElementById("openModal").style.display = 
                 "block";

     }

     function fechaModal(){
          opsc =  document.getElementById("openModal").style.opacity = "0";
          disp =  document.getElementById("openModal").style.display = 
                  "none";

     } 

    </script>
   </head>
  <body>

   <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
      <div>
         <a href="#close" title="Close" onclick="fechaModal();" 
                 class="close">X</a>
        <h2>Modal Box</h2>
        <p>1 paragrafo.</p>
        <p>teste teste teste  teste teste teste v</p>
      </div>
     </div>

     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Veja se é disso que precisa:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" onmouseleave="abreModal()">
   <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

   <title>Document</title>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    var modalJaAberta = false;
      function abreModal() {
        if (!modalJaAberta) {
            modalJaAberta = true;
              opsc = document.getElementById("openModal").style.opacity = "1";
              disp = document.getElementById("openModal").style.display = "block";
        }

     }

     function fechaModal(){
          opsc =  document.getElementById("openModal").style.opacity = "0";
          disp =  document.getElementById("openModal").style.display = "none";

     }

    </script>
   </head>
  <body>

    <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog" style="display: none;">
      <div>
         <a href="#close" title="Close" onclick="fechaModal();" class="close">X</a>
        <h2>Modal Box</h2>
        <p>1 paragrafo.</p>
        <p>teste teste teste  teste teste teste v</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Inicialmente, declarei a variável `modalJaAberta` com valor `false`. Isso significa que assim que carregar sua página, ela automaticamente vai ter o valor `false`.

Quando chamar a função `abreModal()`, ela vai verificar o valor dessa variável. Se o valor for `false`, a *modal* será aberta e atualizará o valor da variável para `true`.

Próxima vez que chamar a função `abreModal()`, a função não fará nada. Pois o valor da variável será `true`.

PS: estilizei a *modal* para funcionar no *snippet*: `style="display: none;"`. Presumo que no seu projeto esteja fazendo-o via *CSS*.